# Creating a user profile using webapp2 on appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

A very simple use case for creating users in webapp2/appengine can be as follows:

```
from google.appengine.api import users


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

But in case we want a user profile which has few more app specific tasks. Say a user can have address and phone number, few of his health info as bloodsugar etc. . How can we extend the user from the api to create a userprofile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a model with a property that links to a user: `db.ReferenceProperty(users.User)`.

Comment: how about login and signup stuff i mean auth etc?